# Suggested edits on meta?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits, meta

When I check [this page](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/review), it says that there' is a suggested edit queue. But aren't suggested edits disallowed on meta? Where did this come from? Is it outdated?.

Comment: [Nooooo! . This is off-topic ! .](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/review/close/59)

Comment: I mean, this definitely *is* off-topic! .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's for tag wiki suggestions. Those still work on meta.